# Migrate all projects from Sourcesafe to Team Foundation Server

Tags: .net, tfs, tfs-migration, sourcesafe-6.0

I would like to migrate all my projects from Sourcesafe to TFS at once, without having to do a project map for each one and creating the corresponding Team Project manually in TFS. How can I do this in the settings.xml. It always requires a destination but I don't want to migrate all my projects to 1 team project. HELP!? I have quite a lot of projects and can manually map them if required, its just time consuming. I don't seem to be getting much help from MSDN.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide this mapping for each VSS project. Even worse, if you do not want to move all projects to 1 team project, you will need to prepare a team project for every project that you want to have migrated on the TFS server on forehand. The converter tools are not able to create team projects out of the blue.

Small trick you could play is to migrate your entire VSS database to a single TFS project called **MigratedFromTFS** or something like that. Every project becomes a first level subdirectory for that project. Then when you actively start to work on a migrated project in TFS2010, create a dedicated project and branch your migrated project subdirectory from the MigratedFromTFS project into the new project workspace. This delays the pain of migration a little until the moment you are actually starting to work on the code again.

Comment: This is a huge pain!  We must have a hundred or so projects.  Thanks for the help.